# cur.fetchall() is not equal to its own supposed value

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

So, I'm trying to build a management system for my school project, and I have to integrate MySQL in that project.
I have defined a `verify_login()` function to make sure there's no mismatch of what screen to show a guest, and what screen to show an admin.

Here's my `verify_login()` function:

```
import mysql.connector as connector

conn = connector.connect(host='localhost', username='root', password='root', database='ip_project')
cur = conn.cursor()

def verify_login(win: Tk, role, pwd):
    cred = [(role.strip().lower(), pwd)]
    
    cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE ROLE = "{role.lower()}"')
    
    if cred == cur.fetchall() and role == 'admin'.casefold():
        win.destroy()
        
        admin()
    elif cred == cur.fetchall() and role == 'guest'.casefold():
        win.destroy()
        
        guest()
    elif cred != cur.fetchall():
        mb.showerror('Login failed!', 'The entered username and password are incorrect! \nPlease recheck them and try again')
```

And here's the login table in MySQL:
[Two columns, role and password. Each columns contains the same values: 'admin' and 'guest'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiabe.png)

**The problem is that whenever cred == cur.fetchall() == [('guest', 'guest')], it shows me the error box, but 60% of the time whenever cred == cur.fetchall() == [('admin', 'admin')] it shows me the admin screen.** (It doesn't always happen with the admin screen, but it happens with the guest screen and whenever I try to login with admin after guest failure, it doesn't happen for the admin screen as well)

Is there any fix to this problem, or it is a glitch??

Comment: Call `fetchall()` only once.  Your code will call it twice if role is not `admin`. The second and later call will return nothing.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for taking time to help me solve this problem! It works after I implemented your suggestion.